# How to use FontIcon and Glyph in ShellPage with XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

The Symbol enum does not cover my icon needs. So I need to use FontIcon and glyph. Is it an easy solution to make this work just like having: Icon="Home"? I cant get it to allign properly. This is my XAML and how it looks in the preview(Profile icon just to illustrate how I want it to look):

```
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Trips" Icon="Home" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" />
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Scanner" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage">
            <FontIcon FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xEE6F;"/>
        </winui:NavigationViewItem>
```

[image]

The profile Icon works like I want it to. How can I achieve this with FontIcon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Scanner" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage">
      <winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
          <FontIcon FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xEE6F;"/>
      </winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
  </winui:NavigationViewItem>
```